# Analogue function of Wolfram Mathematica in Python in NumPy or SciPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, wolfram-mathematica

I am rewriting some code writed in Wolfram Mathematica to Python. And, in some moment I needed an analogue of function [`ArrayResample[array,dspec]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html). May be you know a function from any package (NumPy or SciPy)?

Comment: Can you show the desired input and output of the function please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html#scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates). 
Here are `map_coordinate` equivalents of the [ArrayResample examples](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html):

```
In [51]: import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

In [67]: ndimage.map_coordinates(np.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=float), [np.linspace(0,4,9)], order=1)
Out[67]: array([1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5, 5. ])

In [68]: ndimage.map_coordinates(np.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=float), [np.linspace(0,4,3)], order=1)
Out[68]: array([1., 3., 5.])

In [65]: ndimage.map_coordinates(np.array([(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)], dtype=float), np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,2,6), np.linspace(0,2,6), indexing='ij'), order=1)
Out[65]: 
array([[1. , 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3. ],
       [1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3. , 3.4],
       [1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3. , 3.4, 3.8],
       [2.2, 2.6, 3. , 3.4, 3.8, 4.2],
       [2.6, 3. , 3.4, 3.8, 4.2, 4.6],
       [3. , 3.4, 3.8, 4.2, 4.6, 5. ]])
```

The first argument to `ndimage.map_coordinates` is mainly self-explanatory.
Unlike Mathematica's ArrayResample function, the second argument are the *coordinates* at which you wish to resample the array.

When calling `ndimage.map_coordinates(input, coordinates)`,
if `input` is an N-dimensional array, then `coordinates` is expected to be sequence of `N` arrays -- one array for each axis.

---

If `A` is an array of shape `(h, w)`, and you wish to resample `A` to a new array of shape `(H, W)`,
then you would use

```
ndimage.map_coordinates(A, np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,h-1,H), np.linspace(0,w-1,W), 
                                       indexing='ij'), order=1)
```

[`np.linspace`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) is used to generate equally spaced values between `0` and `h-1` (and `0` and `w-1`). These values are 1D coordinates. [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is used to combine the 1D coordinates into a 2D grid.

Comment: Sorry, can you write last example for matrix N x N?

Comment: I added a general expression for resampling an array of shape `(h, w)` to a new array of shape `(H, W)`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be little non-technical way, but in my opinion(after seeing examples in Wolfram), I am half convinced that np.linspace does the exact same thing that you want with ArrayResample.

So what I mean is:

```
In Wolfram: 
ArrayResample[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 9]
gives:
```

[image]

And similary, numpy, for linespace:

```
np.linspace(1,5,num=9)
gives:
array([1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. , 4.5, 5. ])
```

And also,for:

```
np.linspace(1,5,num=3)
it gives:
array([1., 3., 5.])
```

Is this somewhat what you're looking for or it's much more sophisticated than this?